# MediaElementPlayer in Colorbox

Tags: mediaelement.js

No matter what I've tried, I cannot get the MediaElementPlayer to work in Colorbox. The best I've done so far is get it to work in Chrome and IE9. I only have mp4 files to work with, so for the moment I'm not testing in FF. If I try it in IE8 (standards mode), the video will load and play the first time I click on the Colorbox link to activate it, but I can't see the control buttons. It does, however, play and pause successfully. My cursor turns into the pointer around the center of the video, so probably the controls are there but hidden for some reason. The real problem comes when I close the Colorbox modal and reopen it. The modal opens, but it's empty - no video loads. If I try to close the Colorbox modal at this point, the IE console gives me the following error:

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method
mediaelement-and-player.js, line 3049 character 4

Just in case you're wondering what the offending line is...

```
delete t.node.player;
```

Apparently IE8 Doesn't like it when I try to dispose of the MediaElementPlayer instance. I've checked, and Flash is successfully loading and playing the video. I tried using Fiddler2 to catch the traffic and figure out the problem, but it doesn't show anything. In this simplified example code, I have the src attribute set in the source element of the video element, but I can't do this in the prod code. Why? Because IE completely ignores the "preload='none'" attribute, and since IE9 can play them, all of them load when the page loads. Sometimes there are a lot of videos, so I can't have this. I have a working example of loading the source at runtime when the Colorbox link is clicked, but that suffers from the same problems this one does. I need to be able to open the video more than once without reloading the page. Each video seems to load and play correctly (minus the controls) just once, and after that won't load again. Please take a look through my code and see if there is something I can do to resolve this:

```
<div id="all-container">
    <div id="cbox-links">
        <a href="#video0" width="360px" height="203px" class="cbox cboxElement">Video 1</a><br>
        <a href="#video1" width="720px" height="405px" class="cbox cboxElement">Video 2</a><br>
    </div>
    <div id="mep-container">
        <div class="hidden">
            <video id="video0" width="360" height="203">
                <source src="//s3.amazonaws.com/path-to-video/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden">
            <video id="video1" width="720" height="405">
                <source src="//s3.amazonaws.com/path-to-video/larger_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my script:

```
<script>
    var player = null;
    $(".cbox").colorbox({
        inline: true,
        scrolling: false,
        onOpen: function () {

        },
        onComplete: function () {
            var cboxLink = $(this);

            player = new MediaElementPlayer(cboxLink.attr("href"), {
                alwaysShowControls: true,
                features: [ "playpause", "progress", "volume" ],
                plugins: ['flash'],
                pluginPath: '//s3.amazonaws.com/base-folder/scripts/mediaelement/',
                flashName: 'flashmediaelement.swf',
                success: function (mediaElement, domObject) {
                    console.log("loaded");
                }
            });

            var width  = cboxLink.attr("width");
            var height = cboxLink.attr("height");
            $.fn.colorbox.resize({innerWidth: width, innerHeight: height});
        },
        onCleanup: function () {
            player.pause();
            player.remove();
        }
    });
</script>
```